# Expecting identifier before left bracket

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I continue getting the following error:

> Expecting identifier before left bracket

For the following line below.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

```
public var selectedEvents:[] = [];
```

Comment: For more about [ActionScript 3](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning.html) arrays, take a look [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/arrays.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to create an array, it's `public var selectedEvents:Array = []`.